# "dest.on is not a function" using postcss-rtl with gulp v4

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass, postcss

I'm trying to transform a css document into rtl (right-to-left) using postcss-rtl and automate this using gulp. This is the error I get when I run `gulp watch`:

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (D:\Projects\BootstrapRTL\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:564:8)
    at rtlize (D:\Projects\BootstrapRTL\gulpfile.js:39:8)
    at rtlize (D:\Projects\BootstrapRTL\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:422:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:435:12)
    at asyncRunner (D:\Projects\BootstrapRTL\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

This is my code for the specific function:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const postcss = require("postcss");
const rtl = require("postcss-rtl");

function rtlize() {
  return (
    // 1. Get the css file
    gulp
      .src("./css/main.css")
      // 2. Rtlize the css file
      .pipe(postcss(rtl()))
      // 3. Export the css file
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/rtl"))
  );
}

exports.rtlize = rtlize;
```

Comment: Sounds like the library itself has thrown an error might be a good idea to hunt down the author and raise an issue if they are open source: looks like the error is coming from readable-stream? not sure what that library is ha

Comment: @MarkDavies I found out what's going on. Everything works just fine except I have to use `gulp-postcss` instead of `postcss`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-rtl#with-gulp; from the docs:

```
.pipe( postcss( [ rtl( options ) ]) )  // should be like this
```

Notice `rtl` is in an array.  Not `.pipe(postcss(rtl()))` as you have.